# Data sets for linear inequality and equality constrained quadratic optimization.

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

I'm trying to find some test problems for an algorithm that is solving the problem below:
$$ \begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & x^T Q x + px\\ \text{subject to} & Ax + b = 0\\ \text{    } & Dx + e \leq 0\end{array}$$
However, I haven't found anything that exactly fits my case.
Are there any datasets for this special optimization problem? I guess there have to be some test problems as the above problem appears in many areas.

Comment: Why can't you just randomize some test data?

Comment: @mathreadler, I have done that, but I think it would be better if I tested it with some real data.

Comment: Wait a minute, what is E? Vector or matrix? At first impression big letters seemed to be matrices.

Comment: @mathreadler it's a vector, and you're right I had to use a small letter.

Comment: Ok, I think it is good question. I cannot think of any particular problem right away.

Comment: Try looking for "quadratic programming benchmark problems".